# Best way to validate string input for a limited number of options

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to validate input in MySQL and would like to restrict the input of string values for an attribute to belong to the set `{'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4', 'type5'}`. I've already opted to use an `ENUM{'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4', 'type5'}` datatype. While this seems to prevent insertion of invalid data, it does not provide a descriptive enough error message to the user to reasonably correct the input. The error message is:

> Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1

Which doesn't indicate that I'm looking for one of the enum values. What I'm considering adding is a BEFORE INSERT trigger that checks if the string is valid and fields and error if not. However, I'm pretty unfamiliar with SQL syntax and my implementation seems clunky:

```
IF (NEW.type <> 'Type1' OR
    NEW.type <> 'Type2' OR 
    NEW.type <> 'Type3' OR
    NEW.type <> 'Type4' OR 
    NEW.type <> 'Type5')
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Please ensure 'type' is one of the following: Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, or Type5";
END IF;
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for (i.e. if input belongs to a 'ListOfTypes' instead of using so many ORs), since this can get very clunky with a larger number of valid types. Is this type of double validation even necessary or prudent? I recognize this would prevent me from using indices as inputs, which is one benefit of the `ENUM` datatype. I apologize if this question has an obvious answer. Thanks!

Comment: Shouln't it be `NEW.type <> 'Type1 AND ...'` (with AND instead of OR).

Comment: Correct, good catch there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you do not want to use `ENUM`s, what about using `NOT IN (...)` syntax:

```
IF (NEW.type NOT IN ('Type1','Type2','Type3','Type4','Type5'))
THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Please ensure 'type' is one of the following: Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, or Type5";
END IF;
```